# php if statments all being process even if not matched

Tags: php, opencart

im using the following if statements to add a multiplication to a total if country selected matches a particular multiplication, for some odd reason though no matter which country is selected all the statements are processed ending with a 1 million euro shipping.

any idea whats wrong?

```
if($address['country_id']== '96' or '125')
    {
    $shipp_cost=$shipp_cost * 1;
    }
if($address['country_id']== '162')
    {
    $shipp_cost=$shipp_cost * 1.6;
    }
if($address['country_id']=='133' or '129' or '17' or '230' or '18' or '146' or '168' or '130' or '188' or '184' or '206' or '209' or '44' or '149' or '26' or '100' or '32' or '196' or '107' or '116' or '114' or '113' or '221' or '61' or '57' or '99' or '173')
    {
    $shipp_cost=$shipp_cost * 1.67;
    }
if($address['country_id']=='169' or '13' or '228' or '46' or '118' or '55' or '45' or '158' or '108')
    {
    $shipp_cost=$shipp_cost * 1.8;
    }
if($address['country_id']=='14' or '195' or '201' or '16' or '29' or '223' or '25' or '224' or '31' or '8' or '211' or '5' or '50' or '205' or '27' or '222' or '234' or '204' or '56' or '122' or '159' or '87' or '88' or '170' or '132' or '94' or '97' or '139' or '161' or '163' or '124' or '121' or '142' or '182' or '189' or '70' or '68' or '194' or '71' or '134' or '150' or '84' or '157' or '66')
    {
    $shipp_cost=$shipp_cost * 2;
    }
if($address['country_id']=='38' or '190' or '215' or '214' or '136' or '63' or '213' or '212' or '199' or '191' or '72' or '203' or '144' or            '53' or '83' or '160' or '218' or '11' or '171' or '21' or '20' or '227' or '111' or '110' or '172' or '24' or '101' or '126' or '103' or '104' or '232' or '33')
    {
    $shipp_cost=$shipp_cost * 2.2;
    }
if($address['country_id']=='2' or '98' or '102' or '105' or '219' or '220' or '175' or '60' or '92' or '81' or '77' or '198' or '74' or '73' or '202' or '165' or '140' or '141' or '233' or '138' or '235' or '137' or '148' or '152' or '231')
    {
    $shipp_cost=$shipp_cost * 2.4;
    }
if($address['country_id']=='151' or '7' or '65' or '4' or '19' or '135' or '131' or '22' or '23' or '28' or '64' or '1' or '119' or '120' or '115' or '40' or '3' or '208' or '217' or '181' or '186' or '176' or '216' or '229' or '193' or '155' or '156')
    {
    $shipp_cost=$shipp_cost * 2.6;
    }
if($address['country_id']=='153' or '154' or '147' or '80' or '183' or '93' or '90' or '86' or '15' or '164' or '180' or '109' or '185' or '76' or '41' or '39' or '35' or '178' or '30' or '26' or '225' or '9' or '207' or '51' or '58' or '59' or '69' or '82' or '47' or '210' or '42')
    {
    $shipp_cost=$shipp_cost * 2.8;
    }
if($address['country_id']=='95' or '37' or '239' or '117' or '123' or '238' or '145' or '34' or '226' or '106' or '143' or '43' or '62' or '52' or '85' or '67' or '200' or '179' or '91' or '192' or '78')
    {
    $shipp_cost=$shipp_cost * 3;
    }
if($address['country_id']=='75' or '127' or '48' or '128' or '10' or '197')
    {
    $shipp_cost=$shipp_cost * 3.2;
    }
if($address['country_id']=='187')
    {
    $shipp_cost=$shipp_cost * 3.4;
    }
if($geo_zone=='166' or '174')
    {
    $shipp_cost=$shipp_cost * 3.6;
    }
if($geo_zone=='54')
    {
    $shipp_cost=$shipp_cost * 3.8;
    }
if($geo_zone=='12')
    {
    $shipp_cost=$shipp_cost * 4.8;
    }
if($geo_zone=='6' or '79' or '89' or '167' or '177' or '49')
    {
    $shipp_cost=$shipp_cost * 6;
    }
```

Comment: Create an array and use in_array

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `if` statements won't do what you expect it to:

```
if($address['country_id']== '96' or '125')
{
    $shipp_cost=$shipp_cost * 1;
}
```

Here, the the condition will always evaluate to `TRUE`.

You need the following instead:

```
if($address['country_id'] == '96' or $address['country_id'] == '125')
{
$shipp_cost = $shipp_cost * 1;
}
```

However, using `in_array` is *much* better if you need to check this for a lot of elements:

Store the numbers in an array, and then use the following to check if the given element is in your defined array:

```
$arr = array('133','129','17','230','18','146','168','130','188','184','206','209','44','149','26','100','32','196','107','116','114','113','221','61','57','99','173');

if (in_array($address['country_id'], $arr)) {
    //YAY
}
```

---

As an unrelated sidenote, I think it'd be better to use [`elseif`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.elseif.php) statements in this case.

> `elseif`, as its name suggests, is a combination of `if` and `else`. Like else, it extends an `if` statement to execute a different statement in case the original `if` expression evaluates to `FALSE`. However, unlike `else`, it will execute that alternative expression only if the `elseif` conditional expression evaluates to `TRUE`.

Something like:

```
if(condition) {    
   //code      
}

elseif (condition) {
    //code
}

elseif (condition) {
    //code
}

...
```

The first elseif expression (if any) that evaluates to TRUE would be executed. That way, you can prevent all the `if` statements from getting executed.

Hope this helps!

Comment: oh great thanks was trying with the array but wasnt working either now i know why as well thanks to your explanation.

thanks very much for the insight all working fine :)

Answer (score 1):

You should use like following:

```
if($address['country_id']== '96' or $address['country_id'] == '125') {
    $shipp_cost=$shipp_cost * 1;
} elseif($address['country_id']== '162') {
    $shipp_cost=$shipp_cost * 1.6;
} elseif(...) {
...
```

As alternative `switch case`

```
switch($address['country_id']) 
{
   case 96:
   case 125:
      $shipp_cost=$shipp_cost * 1;
      break;
   case 162:
      $shipp_cost=$shipp_cost * 1.6;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of

```
if($address['country_id']== '96' or '125')
```

try

```
if($address['country_id']== '96' or $address['country_id'] == '125')
```

or take a look at http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php

Answer (score 0):

YOu should try this...

```
if($address['country_id']== '96' or '125')
    {
    $shipp_cost=$shipp_cost * 1;
    }
 elseif($address['country_id']== '162')
    {
    $shipp_cost=$shipp_cost * 1.6;
    }
 elseif($address['country_id']=='133' or '129' or '17' or '230' or '18' or '146' or '168' or '130' or '188' or '184' or '206' or '209' or '44' or '149' or '26' or '100' or '32' or '196' or '107' or '116' or '114' or '113' or '221' or '61' or '57' or '99' or '173')
    {
    $shipp_cost=$shipp_cost * 1.67;
    }
elseif($address['country_id']=='169' or '13' or '228' or '46' or '118' or '55' or '45' or '158' or '108')
    {
    $shipp_cost=$shipp_cost * 1.8;
    }
elseif($address['country_id']=='14' or '195' or '201' or '16' or '29' or '223' or '25' or '224' or '31' or '8' or '211' or '5' or '50' or '205' or '27' or '222' or '234' or '204' or '56' or '122' or '159' or '87' or '88' or '170' or '132' or '94' or '97' or '139' or '161' or '163' or '124' or '121' or '142' or '182' or '189' or '70' or '68' or '194' or '71' or '134' or '150' or '84' or '157' or '66')
    {
    $shipp_cost=$shipp_cost * 2;
    }
elseif($address['country_id']=='38' or '190' or '215' or '214' or '136' or '63' or '213' or '212' or '199' or '191' or '72' or '203' or '144' or            '53' or '83' or '160' or '218' or '11' or '171' or '21' or '20' or '227' or '111' or '110' or '172' or '24' or '101' or '126' or '103' or '104' or '232' or '33')
    {
    $shipp_cost=$shipp_cost * 2.2;
    }
elseif($address['country_id']=='2' or '98' or '102' or '105' or '219' or '220' or '175' or '60' or '92' or '81' or '77' or '198' or '74' or '73' or '202' or '165' or '140' or '141' or '233' or '138' or '235' or '137' or '148' or '152' or '231')
    {
    $shipp_cost=$shipp_cost * 2.4;
    }
elseif($address['country_id']=='151' or '7' or '65' or '4' or '19' or '135' or '131' or '22' or '23' or '28' or '64' or '1' or '119' or '120' or '115' or '40' or '3' or '208' or '217' or '181' or '186' or '176' or '216' or '229' or '193' or '155' or '156')
    {
    $shipp_cost=$shipp_cost * 2.6;
    }
elseif($address['country_id']=='153' or '154' or '147' or '80' or '183' or '93' or '90' or '86' or '15' or '164' or '180' or '109' or '185' or '76' or '41' or '39' or '35' or '178' or '30' or '26' or '225' or '9' or '207' or '51' or '58' or '59' or '69' or '82' or '47' or '210' or '42')
    {
    $shipp_cost=$shipp_cost * 2.8;
    }
elseif($address['country_id']=='95' or '37' or '239' or '117' or '123' or '238' or '145' or '34' or '226' or '106' or '143' or '43' or '62' or '52' or '85' or '67' or '200' or '179' or '91' or '192' or '78')
    {
    $shipp_cost=$shipp_cost * 3;
    }
elseif($address['country_id']=='75' or '127' or '48' or '128' or '10' or '197')
    {
    $shipp_cost=$shipp_cost * 3.2;
    }
elseif($address['country_id']=='187')
    {
    $shipp_cost=$shipp_cost * 3.4;
    }
elseif($geo_zone=='166' or '174')
    {
    $shipp_cost=$shipp_cost * 3.6;
    }
elseif($geo_zone=='54')
    {
    $shipp_cost=$shipp_cost * 3.8;
    }
elseif($geo_zone=='12')
    {
    $shipp_cost=$shipp_cost * 4.8;
    }
elseif($geo_zone=='6' or '79' or '89' or '167' or '177' or '49')
    {
    $shipp_cost=$shipp_cost * 6;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is, you think `if($address['country_id']== '96' or '125')` will test `($address['country_id']== '96') OR ($address['country_id']== '125')`.

That's wrong.
Because `==` has higher precedence than `OR`, it resolves to something like this: `if(($address['country_id'] == '96') or ('125'))`, and the second bracket, i.e. `('125')`, resolves to `true`, and hence each `if` condition is evaluated.

'Higher precedence' simply means that it will bind it's operators more tightly than the one which has lower precedence.
[Here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php) is the PHP's operator precedence table for your reference.